# Extracting the largest object array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a follwoing object array and this will always consist of 3 object inside. 
I would like to return the object that contains the larger value compare to two others.

Preceding object will have sum of their values larger or equal than previous ones. When preceding object return same sum of values to previous ones, value 1 and value 2 should be exactly match. For example,

if sum(data[2]) == sume(data[1]) then value 1 in data[2] is equal to value 1 in data[1] and value2 in data[2] is equal to value1 in data[1] so i can just return either one.

I think I know how to do this in primitive way but what is most elegant way to do this?

In the follwoing example, I would like to return data[2]

```
data = [{
      Area: 'HongKong',
      value1: 163,
      value2: 175,
      DateCreated: 2017 - 11 - 28T17: 59:00.740Z },
    {
      Area: 'HongKong',
      value1: 163,
      value2: 176,
      DateCreated: 2017 - 11 - 28T17: 59:16.747Z },
    {
      Area: 'HongKong',
      value1: 165,
      value2: 176,
      DateCreated: 2017 - 11 - 28T17: 59:32.750Z }]
  })
```

Comment: *"No previous object will have sume of values(value1,value2) larger or equal than prceeding one"* -- Does this mean the array is ordered on the sum of the values? If so, then can you not just take the last element of the array?

Comment: `I have a follwoing object array and this will always consist of 3 object inside` , `Constraint : No previous object will have sume of values(value1,value2) larger or equal than prceeding one`... This means that data[2] is **always** the solution.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, i updated question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [{
      Area: 'HongKong',
      value1: 163,
      value2: 175,
      DateCreated: "2017 - 11 - 28T17: 59:00.740Z" },
    {
      Area: 'HongKong',
      value1: 163,
      value2: 176,
      DateCreated: "2017 - 11 - 28T17: 59:16.747Z" },
    {
      Area: 'HongKong',
      value1: 165,
      value2: 176,
      DateCreated: "2017 - 11 - 28T17: 59:32.750Z" 
    }
];

t0 = performance.now();
console.log(data.sort((a, b) => -(a.value1 + a.value2))[0]);
t1 = performance.now();
console.log("sort took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");

// This the more appropriate way (faster)
t0 = performance.now();
console.log( data.reduce((a,b)=> (a.value1+a.value2) > (b.value1+b.value2) ? a:b ))
t1 = performance.now();
console.log("reduce took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
```

Comment: what does ? a:b mean?

Comment: it's a shorthand for if else ; means if sum of a is larger than b then a else b

Comment: I see.. how does reduce() handle the string in object? does it just exclude any strings inside?

Comment: reduce iterate over the array and each time it gets an object with the accumulator then we can check the sum and return the larger one, and that larger one goes in next iterate to the callback as the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by (value1 + value2) and get the first object.

However what I am not clear is your `No previous object will have sume of values(value1,value2) larger or equal than prceeding one`. If that is the case `data[2]` will always be the answer ain't it? What can be more elegant than that?

```js
const data = [{
      Area: 'HongKong',
      value1: 163,
      value2: 175,
      DateCreated: "2017 - 11 - 28T17: 59:00.740Z" },
    {
      Area: 'HongKong',
      value1: 163,
      value2: 176,
      DateCreated: "2017 - 11 - 28T17: 59:16.747Z" },
    {
      Area: 'HongKong',
      value1: 165,
      value2: 176,
      DateCreated: "2017 - 11 - 28T17: 59:32.750Z" 
    }
];

console.log(data.sort((a, b) => (b.value1 + b.value2) - (a.value1 + a.value2))[0])

console.log(data.sort((a, b) => (a.value1 + a.value2) - (b.value1 + b.value2))[data.length-1])

console.log(data.sort((a, b) => (a.value1 + a.value2))[0])
```

Comment: console.log(data.sort((a, b) => -(a.value1 + a.value2))[0]) this would be enough

Comment: That is correct, but then it is `data.sort((a, b) => (a.value1 + a.value2))[0]` minus sign will return the smallest.

Comment: sort will return from smallest to biggest and minus sign makes it reverse then so [0] will return the maximum. run the code